# Explicit transaction in doctrine2 using transactional method

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I try to implement simple form handling using `EntityManager::transactional(function($em) {});` approach. Seems pretty easy but the question is: how can I pass additional values to such implementation? To be exact I want to do the following

```
$em  = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$request = $this->getRequest();
$form = new BugForm();
$form->get('reporter')->setValueOptions(
    $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Person')->getPersonListArray()
);
$form->get('engineer')->setValueOptions(
    $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Person')->getPersonListArray()
);
$form->get('products')->setValueOptions(
    $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Product')->getProductListArray()
);
$confirmation = "";

if($request->isPost()) {
    $em->transactional(function($em) {
        $form = new BugForm();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if($form->isValid()) {
            $form = new BugForm();
            $hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($em);
            $data = $form->getData();
            $data['created'] = time();
            $data['status'] = 'OPEN';
            $bug = $hydrator->hydrate($data, new Bug());

            $em->persist($bug);
            $em->flush();
            $confirmation = "Created bug with ID ".$bug->getId()."<br/>";
        }
    });
}

return array(
    'form'         => $form,
    'confirmation' => $confirmation
);
```

The problem is that `this->getRequest()` call in anonymous function does not create a data so I am unable to fill BugForm object. Of course I could just use superglobal `_POST` array there but it doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `$this` in an anonymous function you need to be using PHP 5.4 or later. You can also solve your problem by making the `$request` from the parent scope available in the closure's scope by making use of the `use` language construct, like so:

```
$em->transactional(function($em) use ($request) {
    $form = new BugForm();
    $form->setData($request->getPost());
    if($form->isValid()) {
        $form = new BugForm();
        $hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($em);
        $data = $form->getData();
        $data['created'] = time();
        $data['status'] = 'OPEN';
        $bug = $hydrator->hydrate($data, new Bug());

        $em->persist($bug);
        $em->flush();
        $confirmation = "Created bug with ID ".$bug->getId()."<br/>";
    }
});
```

Also you should be aware that the `$confirmation` variable in the closure is in a different scope to the `$confirmation` variable you are returning in the parent function. In order to modify the `$confirmation` variable in the parent scope you should make this avaliable by reference in the closure's scope:

```
$em->transactional(function($em) use ($request, &$confirmation) {
```

Comment: I didn't know about `use` but made an ugly hack with setting `$confirmation` to global. Anyway thanks :)